# How do I get a function in excel to stack data arranged across in several rows to stack in a single coloumn on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I've been attempting to pull a large amount of data currently arranged in rows into a separate worksheet in excel and have it stack into a single coloumn such that I can upload to microstrategy to analyse.
Ideally I want

```
a1  b1  c1  d1  
a2  b2  c2  d2  
a3  b3  c3  d3
```

to become

```
a1
b1
c1
d1
a2
b2
c2
d2
a3
b3
c3
d3
```

I have some quite large data sets and would need to do this regularly so was hoping to create a VBA script to achieve this that could be easily modified and applied to other worksheets. I also would prefer not to copy and paste values but have links to the other worksheet so when the source is updated so is the destination. I've got as far as managing to get 

`a1
b1
c1
d1`

Using the following code

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer, ii As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2") 

For i = 1 To 4

    ws.Cells(1 +ii, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "='Sheet1'!R1C" & i

     ii = ii + 1

 Next

End Sub
```

My problem arises when trying to formulate a loop to factor in the change of rows. My attempts so far have proved fruitless and frustrating; I've managed to get a diagonal of a1 b2 c3 or a stack of a1 b2 a3 b4 a5 b6 but can't seem to achieve the desired result. I feel it's not incredibly difficult but formulating the correct loop has evaded me so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: didnt you try to copy data via VB, not setting a formula? like     'Sheet2.Cells(1 +ii, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(r,c)' having Sheets 1 and 2 as worksheer, r for row and c for column?

Comment: Can we assume that (1) there is no whitespace between values within the rows, (2) there are no empty rows, and (3) all info starts in column A for each row that has data?

Comment: @Salek yes this is one option but as stated in the queston ideally I would like the links present.

Comment: @Taelsin (1) yes there's no whitespace between values in the rows(but I don't see how this would affect the script)(2) There's no empty rows(Again don't see what bearing this would have)(3)Info starts from coloumn H but can easily adjust to this by altering the I value in the script above

Comment: @Cormac They're mostly used for a stop condition when doing what chillin suggested as a more efficient solution in his answer. If the data is packed nicely (whitespace only at the end of rows and columns) then you can use empty cells as a signal to move on to the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

With thisworkbook

' The first cell to stack downward from (will include the cell you specify), plus sheet name.'
Dim OutputSheetRange as range
Set OutputSheetRange = .worksheets("Sheet2").range("A1")

' Change this to the worksheet containing the cells that need to be stacked.'
With .Worksheets("Sheet1")

 Dim FormulaPrefix as string
    FormulaPrefix = "='" & .name & "'!"

' Code assumes range below, but change to whatever you need.'
With .range("A1:D4")

Dim RowCount as long
RowCount = .rows.count

Dim ColumnCount as long
ColumnCount = .columns.count

Dim ColumnIndex as long
Dim RowIndex as long
Dim OutputIndex as long

OutputIndex = 0



For ColumnIndex = 1 to ColumnCount
For RowIndex = 1 to RowCount

OutputSheetRange.offset(OutputIndex,0).formula = FormulaPrefix & .cells(rowindex,columnindex).address
OutputIndex = OutputIndex + 1

Next RowIndex
Next Columnindex

End With

End with

End Sub
```

This code might take a while for larger data sets (assuming it works). It would be far more efficient to read the input range into a two dimensional array, stack the values within memory, then write stacked values back to the sheet in a single operation -- but this wouldn't preserve any links/update upon recalculation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. You can do it with a few clicks. Do like this:

1. Select the data range
2. Go to the Data tab and click *From Table/Range*
3. Ok the range
4. In the new window that opens, select all columns
5. Go to the Transform tab
6. Click *Unpivot columns*
7. Back to the Home tab and click *Close and load*

Comment: Which Excel version is that?

Comment: @pnuts your correct friend - But OP is asking to **create a VBA script to achieve this**

Comment: @sam Yes I don't "need" to use VBA but doing it this way would be quite labour intensive as this task will be repeated regularly and I'm dealing with data sets on the scale of hundreds of rows so the more I can automate the process the better